# Use Boolean expression in pgfplots settings

Tags: pgfplots

How can I use a Boolean expression in a pgfplots setting? I'm trying to set every other plot to `forget plot`, which I'm able to do (pictured) using the commented out lines in the example below, but when I try to accomplish this with only one `\addplot` through various methods, only one of which is shown below, I always get an error.

I'm sure I'm missing something due to my inexperience. This should be very simple.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{
x a a+1 b b+1 c c+1
0 0 1 4 5 5 6
2 1 2 3 4 5.5 6.5
}\loadedtable
\begin{axis}[
    cycle list={red, green, blue},
    every axis plot/.append style={very thick, mark=*},
    forget plot style={dotted, mark=none},
]

% \foreach \n in {6,5,...,1}{
\foreach \n [evaluate=\n as \ctrTF using \ifodd\n true \else false \fi] in {6,5,...,1}{
    \addplot table [x=x, y index=\n, forget plot/.expanded=\ctrlTF, ] {\loadedtable};
    \ifodd\n
        % \addplot table [x=x, y index=\n] {\loadedtable};
        \pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex{\n}\of{\loadedtable}\to\colname
        \addlegendentryexpanded{\colname}
    % \else
        % \addplot+[forget plot] table [x=x, y index=\n] {\loadedtable};
    \fi
}

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by replacing the `\foreach` loop with the following.

```
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{6,...,1}{
    \ifodd#1
        \def\toforget{false}
        \pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex{#1}\of{\loadedtable}\to\colname
        \addlegendentryexpanded{\colname}
    \else
        \def\toforget{true}
    \fi
    \addplot+ [forget plot=\toforget] table [x index=0, y index=#1] {\loadedtable};
}
```